# Use of to-infinitive in passive construction

Tags: passive-voice

> My own instinct would have been to remove them.

I think, the above sentence is in passive construction. In passive construction, we need to use past participle form verb. And in the above sentence, **been** is the past participle of verb, and if we want to use another verb after past participle of verb in passive construction, we will have to use **to-infinitive**. Am I right?

Comment: It's tricky, but I don't think that sentence is not in passive construction.  Passive would be "My own instinct would have been **to have them removed**."  The sentence looks like the passive because of *been*, but I think it's actually the **conditional perfect**.  The conditional perfect is used in hypotheticals in the past, like "I would have been hungry".

Comment: From *Practical English Usage* 412.5 (on "students often confuse active and passive verb forms in English"): "Mistakes like these are not surprising, because: 1. *Be* is used to make both passive verb forms and active progressive tenses. 2. Past participles are used to make both passive verb forms and active perfect tenses."

Comment: Argh, I meant "I don't think that sentence **is** in passive construction."

Answer (score 1):

This is not a passive sentence, but an active sentence employing a past-tense modal perfect.

The main verb, the final verb in the group is *BE*. Note that the verb *BE* **cannot** be cast in the passive, because it is intransitive: it does not take a Direct Object.

If we rewrote your sentence in the simple present it would read:

> My instinct **is** to remove them.

*BE* takes the past participle form *been* because it is the complement of *HAVE* in the perfect construction. In the present perfect this sentence would read:

> My instinct **has been** to remove them.

*HAVE* takes the infinitive form *have* because it is the complement of *would*. Modal verbs always require the following verb to take the "unmarked" infinitive form—that is, an infinitive without the marker *to*.

> My instinct **would have been** to remove them.

In the phrase *to remove them* the verb *REMOVE* is cast as a marked infinitive, *to remove*, because that is how we express the complement of the noun *instinct*: guard dogs have an instinct **to attack** intruders, mothers have an instinct **to protect** their children. This complement is also employed for the Predicative Complement of a linking verb when *instinct* is the Subject:

> A mother's instinct is to protect her children.
>   My instinct is to remove them. *(see my first 'rewrite' above)*